# Getting Web table data into excel

Tags: vba

I wanted to get monthly data from "https://investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-historical-data" into excel through vba.

Here is the source code of Time Frame dropdown menu:-

```
<select id="data_interval" class="newInput selectBox float_lang_base_1">
        <option value="Daily" selected="">Daily</option>
        <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
        <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
    </select>enter code here
```

Here is the Table source Code:

```
<table class="genTbl closedTbl historicalTbl" id="curr_table" tablesorter="">enter code here
```

Here is the VBA code I am using,

```
Sub GetData()
Dim IE As Object
Dim Links
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate ("https://uk.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-historical-data")
IE.Visible = True
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = 4
Set Links = IE.document.getElementById("data_interval")
Links.selectedIndex = 2
End Sub
```

2 is the Monthly Index number, It can select the Monthly from dropdown menu but the table not update itself from weekly to Monthly, I am also wanting to get this data into excel

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, it may work for you, depending on your Internet Explorer.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()

    Dim IE      As Object
    Dim Links   As Object
    Dim evt     As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.navigate ("https://uk.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-historical-data")
    IE.Visible = True
    Do
        DoEvents        
    Loop Until IE.readyState = 4

    Set Links = IE.document.GetElementById("data_interval")
    Set evt = IE.document.createevent("htmlevents")
    evt.initevent "change", True, False

    Links.Focus
    Links.SelectedIndex = 2
    Links.FireEvent ("onChange")

    Links.dispatchevent evt

End Sub
```

Tribute to [these guys](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/excel/325370-vba-ie9-fireevent-method.html) for firing the event correctly.

Comment: Thanks buddy, its worked on previous version of IE but not current IE version.

Comment: Very nice approach  + 1